# Registering custom CollectionViewCells to one CollectionView inside a View component

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a component that has a CollectionView inside. I'm using this view inside a class as an IBOutlet as below.

```
class MyClass {
    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomView: MyCustomView!
}
```

Inside MyCustomView I have a function which register custom cells.

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
    didSet {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}


func configureCollectionView(identifier: String, cell: AnyObject.Type) {
    self.collectionView.register(cell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
   }
}
```

This function is being called inside MyClass with a custom collectionViewCell as below. What I try to achieve is registering different cells to a custom CollectionViewCell.

```
class MyClass {
@IBOutlet weak var myCustomView: MyCustomView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initializeCustomView()
   }

private func initializeCustomView() {
        myCustomView.configureCollectionView(identifier: String, cell: MyCustomCell.Type)
     }
}
```

When I do this, IBOutlets of my custom collectionViewCells are getting nil with the error below. Why this happens? or Is this kind of structure possible?

*Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value*

Comment: A general advice: Stop using storyboards. They're error-prone and hard to debug.
The error: An optional value is not set even though you're calling it. The only optional values I see in your code are the views so I guess you haven't connected the views to your code properly

Comment: I have connected them